# Grid alignment in Bootstrap on small devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a 3 column row with three images using the bootstrap. Just like below.

|         |        |        |
|         |        |        |
|         |        |        |
|         |        |        |
|--------------------- | 
|         |        |        |
|         |        |        |
|         |        |        |
|         |        |        |

In smaller devices, I have problem where I could see only two column and one column with empty content. Is there anyway that I can join these two rows together and to get a 2x2 2x2 2x2 schema on smaller devices?

My markup

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you two columns on small devices and three columns on tablet and up. The `.clearfix` ensures that the columns clear their floats properly.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"></div>
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"></div>
  <div class="clearfix hidden-xs"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"></div>
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can put everything in a single row and use `col-xs-6` so that width switches to 50% on smaller screens..

```
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"> </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"> </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"> </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"> </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"> </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"> </div>
  </div>
```

**Demo:** http://bootply.com/mHzFhOfWzQ

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to have these items flow automatically by using the right `col-*` classes. Something like this:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
```

If that doesn't work for you, you can apply the `hidden-*` classes to show separate rows for the size of the viewport.

```
<div class="row hidden-sm">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
<div class="row hidden-sm">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
</div>

<div class="row hidden-lg">
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
<div class="row hidden-lg">
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
<div class="row hidden-lg">
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
```

This isn't the best, kind of a hack, but can work if you can't get anything else to work. Check this out for more [information on how to do this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities).